# What would a theoretical Group II, Group IV Transistor's Properties be?

Tags: transistors, semiconductors, theory

This question is for more than a theory.

I would like to disprove that what I'm working on is not a Group II, Group IV transistor.

I know they CAN exist. I don't know why they don't exist or what their properties would be.

So, q1.
What would their properties be as an npn and as a pnp?

q2
How could a circuit be formed to prove or disprove that the device is this type of transistor?

It definitely has Group II and Group IV elements with silicon and heavily doped elements and I think most likely in the PNP configuration. But it doesn't act like a normal Group III-V transistor.

Any semiconductor experts out there?

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it should be migrated to Physics.SE

Comment: Physics SE or electrochem.SE?

Comment: @ElliotAlderson This has been moved to PhysicSE

Comment: Crossposted to https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/702196/2451

Comment: This question has now been reposted on [Physics.SE](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/702196) so as a question shouldn't be active on multiple SE sites at the same time (to avoid duplication of effort) the question is being closed here. Those people interested in this question should follow the link to Physics.SE.

Comment: @Qmechanic - Thanks for the link!